# Delphi OTL Multithreading UI freezes

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

The UI freezes during execution of my OTL multithreaded program.
Tested with one to 16 thread, UI freezes immediately after procedure start.

```
  Parallel.ForEach(0, CalcList.Count-1)
  .NumTasks(nMax) 
  .NoWait
  .Execute(
   procedure(const value: integer)
   begin
     CalcUnit.EntrySearch(value);
    end)
```

All thread messages are correctly received by the OmniEventMonitor. When all threads are closed the OmniEventMonitor handles all the received messages at once.
     How can I determine what causes the freezing to find a resolution. `Application.ProcessMessages` and/or `OmniTED.ProcessMessages` 
in the `OmnitEventMonitorTaskMessage` does have no influence.

for a MCVE:
on mainform:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Parallel.ForEach(0, 1)
  .Execute(
     procedure(const value: integer)
     begin
       CalcUnit.EntrySearch;
     end);
 end;
```

on the CalcUnit

```
procedure EntrySearch;
var
   I : integer ;
begin
  for I := 1 to 10 do begin
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    Sleep(1000) ;
   end;
 end;
```

the MainForm freezes until the CalcUnit is completed.

Comment: Why would you be calling `ProcessMessages`? Could we have an MCVE?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your fast reply. Hoped to unfreeze the mainthread with ProcessMessages, (did not work)

Comment: The "hope to unfreeze" is sometimes referred to as "programming by accident". It's important to understand what `ProcessMessages` does when you use it. It's misuse can lead to a nightmare of subtle problems. .... As for why your UI is freezing? That will be due to something inside the `CalcUnit.EntrySearch` method (or something it calls etc.).

Comment: In order to solve the problem you must first diagnose and understand it. That will take debugging of some sort. We cannot do that with no code. You need to either show code, an MCVE, or do the debugging yourself.

Comment: @CraigYoung thank you for your comments, English is not my native language. I know what ProcessMessages does, been using Delphi since Delphi 4. Although New to Multithreading. The ProcessMessages I used to handle messages, via the OmniEventMonitor, from the threads to set a Progress Bar, (Didn't work). Inside the threads I did remove all connections to the MainForm but did not solve the freezing.

Comment: You should need ProcessMessages. We can't help until we have the detail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks you for your comments.
I have removed everything out the CalcUnit.Entry until only the reading of a data file remained. Did move DataFiles to another location and did change the FileData format.

      AssignFile(qInputFile, Path);
      Reset(qInputFile);
      while Not eof(qInputFile) do begin
        with qWallRec  Do begin
          Read (qInputFile, qWallRec);
         {reading the lines and the contents into an array}
        end; {With qWallRec}
      end; this file readings is done about 350 times. Nothing changed the Freezing. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: I don't know either. You've got more hope than I do though because you can see the code. So, good luck with your efforts to work it out.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry for the lack of an MCVE, tried to make one for my CPU usage problem, but failed.
Now I could make a MCVE for the Freezing problem. What can I do with the MCVE? do I attach a zip file somewhere or can I post the code somewhere? Thanks Frits

Comment: Post the code in the question. It needs to be simple enough to do that. So you'll need to cut it down to a bare minimum.

Comment: In your updated question, the `.NoWait` is not included. This means (I think) that the `Button1Click` method is waiting until the parallel task is completed == GUI freeze.

Comment: But there is more to this, see [Why is OmniThreadLibrary's ForEach blocking main thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16880457/576719).

Comment: @LURD Thank for your comments. The NoWait makes no difference, In my original code the NoWait is used and MainForm freezes, I will study your link, Thanks again

Comment: @LURD with your link I could make my main thread not Freeze anymore, however one thread will not close, so program will not close. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I could not help more. OTL is not in my toolbox, since I use my own multithreading framework.

Comment: It's obvious why the code in the question blocks the main thread. The ForEach blocks until it completes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks, Yes David you are right. shall I delete or end my question?

Comment: You could perhaps add an answer and that would get it done. Now that you've edited the question it is a decent question.

Answer (score 0):

The Application UI freezes because it is waiting for all threads have been completed. I had to destroy the ForEach interface at task Completion. Used the OnStop method in the MainForm to destroy the last Thread. Look at: [Incrementing Progress Bar from a ForEach Loop](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2014/07/incrementing-progress-bar-from-foreach.html#links)

```
{Private declarations}
FWorker : IOmniParallelLoop<integer>;

FWorker := Parallel.ForEach(0, CalcList.Count-1)
.TaskConfig(Parallel.TaskConfig.OnMessage(Self))
.NumTasks(nMax) 
.NoWait
.OnStop(procedure (const task: IOmniTask)
  begin
  task.Invoke(procedure begin
      FWorker := nil;
    end);
  end);

FWorker
.Execute(
  procedure (const value: integer)
  begin
     CalcUnit.EntrySearch(value);
  end);
```